# How do I migrate CCK filefield?

Tags: 7, entities, files

I'm migrating a Drupal 6 site with CCK filefields to Drupal 7. I installed the Drupal 7 CCK module, and I'm ready to do the migration except for a filefield field.

Migrate fields states:

> Missing field module: 'filefield'. This field cannot be migrated.

The filefield module isn't available for Drupal 7. Is there an other module, or any other way of migrating a Drupal 6 CCK filefield to Drupal 7 fields?

#### Update

I just realized it's an audiofield. Basically it's a filefield with an audio widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether I should call this a solution or a workaround. Anyway:

In D6 I removed audio representation of the filefield. This makes it an ordinary filefield. Then migrated to D7 using the CCK migration kit and then added the audio representation again. Done.

Answer (score -1):

Please read [Migrating D6 Content Construction Kit (CCK) to D7 Fields](https://drupal.org/node/1144136).

Basically you've to download [CCK module](http://drupal.org/project/cck) for 7.x and it has the functionality to migrate these fields.